# Installing a custom webservice

Tags: development, web-services, asp.net, installation, wsdl

I am trying to install some (old) bespoke software which contains Sharepoint webservices. Unfortunatly I don't have the documentation for this software, if there ever was any.

I have been reading up on the MSDN and some other website I found on google to figure this out but the web services have confused me.

[This Site](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/sharepoint-blog/creating-a-custom-web-service-for-sharepoint-13553) suggests that the `.disco` and `.wsdl` files should be renamed with the `.aspx` extension. Which the disco/wsdl files I have already for the installation do not have.

They are also formatted differently to the example in the above website.

here is the `lists.disco` file I have.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<discovery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/">
<contractRef ref="http://deimos/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl" docRef="http://deimos/_vti_bin/lists.asmx" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/scl/" />
<soap address="http://deimos/_vti_bin/lists.asmx" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" binding="q1:ListsSoap" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/soap/" />
<soap address="http://deimos/_vti_bin/lists.asmx" xmlns:q2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" binding="q2:ListsSoap12" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/disco/soap/" />
</discovery>
```

and here is the `lists.wsdl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <s:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
  <s:import namespace="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" />
  <s:element name="GetList">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetListResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListAndView">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="viewName" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListAndViewResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetListAndViewResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="DeleteList">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="DeleteListResponse">
    <s:complexType />
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="AddList">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="templateID" type="s:int" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="AddListResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AddListResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="AddListFromFeature">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="description" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="featureID" type="s1:guid" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="templateID" type="s:int" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="AddListFromFeatureResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AddListFromFeatureResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="UpdateList">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listProperties">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="newFields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="updateFields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="deleteFields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listVersion" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="UpdateListResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UpdateListResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListCollection">
    <s:complexType />
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListCollectionResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetListCollectionResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListItems">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="viewName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="query">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="viewFields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="rowLimit" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="queryOptions">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="webID" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListItemsResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetListItemsResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListItemChanges">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="viewFields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="since" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contains">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListItemChangesResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetListItemChangesResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListItemChangesSinceToken">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="viewName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="query">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="viewFields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="rowLimit" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="queryOptions">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="changeToken" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contains">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListItemChangesSinceTokenResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetListItemChangesSinceTokenResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="UpdateListItems">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="updates">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="UpdateListItemsResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UpdateListItemsResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="AddDiscussionBoardItem">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="message" type="s:base64Binary" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="AddDiscussionBoardItemResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AddDiscussionBoardItemResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetVersionCollection">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="strlistID" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="strlistItemID" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="strFieldName" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetVersionCollectionResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetVersionCollectionResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="AddAttachment">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listItemID" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fileName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="attachment" type="s:base64Binary" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="AddAttachmentResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AddAttachmentResult" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetAttachmentCollection">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listItemID" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetAttachmentCollectionResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetAttachmentCollectionResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="DeleteAttachment">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listItemID" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="url" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="DeleteAttachmentResponse">
    <s:complexType />
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="CheckOutFile">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="pageUrl" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="checkoutToLocal" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="lastmodified" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="CheckOutFileResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckOutFileResult" type="s:boolean" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="UndoCheckOut">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="pageUrl" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="UndoCheckOutResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="UndoCheckOutResult" type="s:boolean" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="CheckInFile">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="pageUrl" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="comment" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckinType" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="CheckInFileResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckInFileResult" type="s:boolean" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListContentTypes">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contentTypeId" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListContentTypesResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetListContentTypesResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListContentType">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contentTypeId" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="GetListContentTypeResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetListContentTypeResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="CreateContentType">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="displayName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="parentType" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contentTypeProperties">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="addToView" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="CreateContentTypeResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CreateContentTypeResult" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="UpdateContentType">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contentTypeId" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contentTypeProperties">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="newFields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="updateFields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="deleteFields">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="addToView" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="UpdateContentTypeResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UpdateContentTypeResult">
          <s:complexType mixed="true">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="DeleteContentType">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="listName" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="contentTypeId" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  //Code ommited - space
```

//Ommited the rest due to space limit

I assumed that these files would already be set up to be discoverable by Sharepoint? Is it possible to tell or dededuce information about the manner in which this should be installed by the code?

For example in the disco file it `<soap address="http://deimos/_vti_bin/lists.asmx">` safe to assume that you need a IIS site called "deimos" to use this.

Answer (score 1):

The [lists.asmx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.aspx) is a standard SharePoint web service. So you should not install that.

It seems that the software you're installing may be using web services instead of exposing them.

Answer (score 0):

just put your .asmx to the Layouts directory.

if you want put them in the _vti_bin, like list.asmx. you need to make the .diso and .wsdl file. not suggestion......